# Can't access my xampp server remotely

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I can't access my xampp server remotely. I have added `Allow from all` line in my httpd-xampp.txt and now it looks like:

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

But still I'm unable to access it remotely. Also my firewall is turned off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use your network IP adress instead of localhost (127.0.0.0).

If you are behind the firewall, you need to allow incoming connections for port 80, maybe for mysql port also (if you plan to use remove SQL management software).

Most probably you'l also need to configure your router ( if your have one ), to route all incoming connections from 80 port to your web server subnet address.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/[path to your]/htdocs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: when i changed this line iget Error 403 Access forbidden!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is your firewall. please disable the firewall and recheck